# jQuery datepick pre select the year to show all months and days

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery datepicker

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
minDate: "-150Y",
maxDate: "-18Y",
yearRange: '1900:1995'
```

which shows a date range of a min 18 years old however the default calendar blocks out the days and months less than 18 years. This is slightly confusing to my customers as they don't realise if they are born in a month after the current 18 year restriction to select the year then the month then the day.

My question is, is there a way to preset the year dropdown to be 1 year greater than 18 so all months and days are shown?

So currently the default selections are Jul 1995 but I would like default selections to be July 1994.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Sure http://jsfiddle.net/tbTQw/

Comment: Why not `maxDate: "-19Y"`?

Comment: That wont work because the max date can be 18 years not 19 years and changing the maxDate to 19 just makes 1995 unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will default the date to 19 years from today. (use the `defaultDate` option)
(http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtDateOfBirth").datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "img/iconography/date-picker-icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        minDate: "-100Y",
        maxDate: "-18Y",
        defaultDate: "-19Y" // <<<<<<
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbTQw/2/

Comment: Technically, this defaults the date to 19 years AGO. I did the same with just '-1Y' to set the date one year previous to solve this myself.